# Query JSON MySql expanding comment fields example

Tags: java, jquery, json

I'm looking to create a page for people's comments.
This page will allow an initial comment, then replies to the comment and replies to that etc etc.
So potentially the 'nest' of comments is infinit.

Therefore I do not want to get all results in one go, instead I want to initially get the original comments, then get the replies as and when the user clicks on the parent comemnt

So for example

```
Comment1
Comment2
Comment3
```

Would be my original list

Click on Comment2 and you now see:

```
Comment1
Comment2
> Reply1
> Reply2
Comment3
```

Click on Reply2 and now you see

```
Comment1
Comment2
> Reply1
> Reply2
>> Reply3
>> Reply4
>> Reply5
Comment3
```

The comments are stored in MYSQL DB, with a Java/JSP base webapp.

Thinking this is a jQuery/JSON job, so really just wondering if anyone has an example or link to an example I can work from.

TABLE STRUCTURE

### id|comment|parent_id

1, comment_1, 0
2, comment_2, 0
3, comment_3, 1
4, comment_4, 3
5, comment_5, 3
6, comment_6, 2
7, comment_7, 0
8, comment_8, 7
9, comment_9, 8
10, comment_10, 5
11, comment_11, 9
12, comment_12, 11
13, comment_13, 6
14, comment_14, 12
15, comment_15, 13

With Comments object.

Thanks in advance

KS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to get you started. jQuery and JSON does indeed sound like a good idea here, unless you of course want to step it up a notch and using a full fledged JavaScript MVC / MVVM framework.

```
// Assuming comments are in the class 'comments' and that
// each comment has a unique ID.
$('comment').on('click', function(e) {
    var commentId = e.attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your/api/url/' + commentId,
        method: 'GET'
    }).success(function(data) {
        // Assuming children are in an array called 'comments'
        if (data && data.comments) {
             // Inject children as HTML
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Forgot to add my table structure. You are correct to assume I have a Comments class. Added my table to my original post.  Cheers.